# Highcharts Error 15 if xSeries has number in it

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Looking at the example at http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/ if you change the label of `Apples` to `Apples 1` (http://jsfiddle.net/w7qyysxr/) then you get the error #15 and your chart is messed up. The data module is trying to parse the label as date and thus you get the error.

I want to know if there is a workaround for this bug, maybe tell the data module not to parse the names as dates (or something like that).

Comment: Yes, I can see what you see. Is there any question related to this?

Comment: I want to know if there is a workaround for this bug, maybe tell the data module not to parse the names as dates (or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple workaround would be to set parseDates to not parse dates. Like this:

```
data: {
  table: 'datatable',
  parseDate: function(dates) {}
},
```

Of course, if you needed to parse some dates, you could put whatever logic you want in that function.

**Working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/w7qyysxr/2/

**API on data.parseDates**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parseDate

Comment: Thanks, this works. The example you have provided contains `xAxis: {type: 'categories'},` I had to remove that for the series name to appear correctly

Comment: Great, I updated the fiddle link now so that it shows correctly.